# Disable date other than the current date with DevExpress DateEdit

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How to disable a date other than the current date in c# devexpress dateedit

In the load event:

```
dtDate.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
```

On view:

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="dtDate" runat="server" EditFormatString="d MMM yyyy"></dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

But it does not work, what is wrong or missing?

Comment: And whats wrong? Probably you should use load event of the DateEdit itself (like explained here http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `DateEdit.DateTime` value in the `DateEdit.KeyPress` event, and then set  `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` to be `true`

thanks

Comment: i not understand what your purpose ? please implement the code you mean. thanks you so much.. and i really hope u... =)